# Changing title page features in quarto slideshow in theme

Tags: reveal.js, quarto

I'm trying to make a custom theme for quarto, and I can't find any references to being able to put title page features like background into the theme, only into the YAML. Is this because it's not possible, or am I (hopefully) just missing it?

Comment: By custom theme, do you mean a `custom.scss` file passed to `theme` yaml key?

Comment: @shafee - exactly, that's what I'm hoping for

Comment: using `custom.scss` file you, at best, can change the title background (Not the background of whole title slide) and title font family AFAIK. For the rest of things like title slide background image, logo, background color, you need to rely on `title-slide-attributes` yaml key.

Comment: @shafee - got it, that's all I could find too, thanks!